# How to use a mustache file as the source of a template in dart?

Tags: dart, mustache

In golang you can pass a file as the source of the template, for example:

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("hello.gohtml")
```

But I can't figure it out, how to do this simple thing in dart using the mustache package.

I would think, it is something similar to this. But this just print *hello.mustache*.

main.dart

```
import 'package:mustache/mustache.dart';

main() {
 var data = { 'name': 'foo' };
 var template = new Template('hello.mustache');

 var output = template.renderString(data);
 print(output);
}
```

hello.mustache

```
<h1>hello, {{name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file and then parse it:

```
var template = Template(File('hello.mustache').readAsStringSync());
```